# Is there any textbook about computing the automorphism group of the triangle group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, hyperbolic-geometry

For example computing the automorphism group of the 2 genus surface made by triangles (12,2,3) in the hyperbolic plane. In addition,if you know the trick of the computing the automorphism groups like that please give me some ideas! Thank you!

Comment: Could be.  The big book is Wilhelm Magnus, Noneuclidean Tesselations and Their Groups , (1974).

Comment: @Will Jagy, thank you, but I just checked the book but found nothing about automorphism, are you sure is this book? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If $\Gamma$ is the Fuchsian group such that $S=\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$ then $\mbox{Aut}(S)$ is the quotient of $\Gamma$ by its normalising subgroup, and is necessarily finite. I'm afraid I don't know how to compute what this group is for your particular example.

Comment: Thank you, and where can I find the words you said above. I really want to read that. Thank you!

Comment: A reference is Proposition 2.35 in the book: Introduction to Compact Riemann Surfaces and Dessins d'Enfants, Girondo, Gonzalez-Diez, 2012.

Comment: @ Matthew Thank you very much!